# Use of unassigned local variable 'num7' and 'num1'

Tags: c#

`if ((uint)(-(num2 == num3 ? 1 : 0) & str.IndexOf("}") & -(str.IndexOf("#include") == -1 ? 1 : 0)) > 0U && str.IndexOf("(") != -1)`

after i fixed the num1 and num7 values i get and overflow error in this line

Comment: Above duplicate was found by copying your question title into google. Please do your own research/effort first.

Comment: There are millions.. no, not millions, BILLIONS article on Google about that error message.

Comment: reading error message would also be great: you are using (getting) the value of a variable before setting a value for it.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't assigned a value to `num1` or `num7`.

in your code, you have the below:

```
checked { ++num7; }
```

However, you didn't initialise `num7`, and you can't add 1 to a null value. You need to initialise `num7`.

```
long num7 = 0;
```

You should also intialise `num1` in the same way.

There's probably a lot easier way to do whatever it is you are trying to do as well.

Also, you aren't using some variables. I see `num4` is assigned a value, but it is only ever used to initialise `num6`. The same can be said for `num2`, so is there any point in even having them?

Answer (score 2):

In a *method scope*, you must initialize local variable  :

```
long num1 = 0; 
long num7 = 0;
```